# Error: Algorithm not found with correct processing use

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-3, algorithm, python-3, pyqgis-3

I try to run a simple dissolve algorithm in a standalone Python 3 script. My code is following :

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

layer = QgsVectorLayer(layerPath, 'layer 1', 'ogr')

parameters = {'INPUT': layer,
              'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}
dissolved = processing.run('gdal:dissolve', parameters)
```

But Python tells me : `Error: Algorithm not found`

But when I print the list of available algorithms :

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, [alg.id() for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms()])))
```

I get the algorithm ID I try to use...

I run my scripts with a batch to include all libraries :

```
@echo off
set OSGEO4W_ROOT="C:\QGIS 3.0"
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python\plugins;%PYTHONPATH%
rem "%PYTHONHOME%\python" %*
%PYTHONHOME%\python .\main.py %*
```

Is there something I forgot to import or to do ?

**EDIT :**
after reinstalling QGIS I have another error message :

```
File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 96, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 125, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm gdal:dissolve not found
```

But `processing.algorithmHelp("gdal:dissolve")` is working correctly...

Any idea ?

Comment: Don't you have to start qgis first with `QgsApplication.initQgis()`? Not sure if this still a thing in qgis 3.0 but it would cause a similar issue in version 2.8

Comment: Please see my comment below. The error comes from QGIS installation.

Answer (score 1):

I complete my message because I found the source of this bug. When I open QGIS 3 I get following error :

```
Plugin processing. The plugin will be disabled because it crashed qgis during last startup.
```

Have you ever had this problem ?

Comment: do this message show everytime you open it? or only if you open it after running the script? the crash mentioned in this error could be the one caused by the script

Comment: This is my error now :
`File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 96, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.2\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 125, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm gdal:dissolve not found`

Comment: can you update your question with the changes you made to get this error?

Comment: That's done. Hope someone has a solution.